# hyper link pop up Window in JQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, popup

I am trying to add pop up window on hyper link but not the default one that is `windows.open()`. I want a window like Google Compose mail. I did try the **Angular.js** but can't understand the main concept to produce that. If any one can help me as I did try other JavaScript Libraries like **colorbox**, **fancybox** etc. They work fine on button but not on hyper link.

Comment: Maybe you should post the "hyper link" and some of the code you've tried ?

Comment: It should work on `hyperlinks` just check the examples in http://fancybox.net/ , they all work in `hyperlinks` and `images`